# How to use bullet gem in development env with cache enabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing a Rails app for N+1 Query. For that I using `bullet` gem.
Which advice me to use eager loading using `:includes`. But When I do use `:include` It tells me to avoid use eager loading and I should remove `:includes` from my finder. The query is like:

```
user.notifications.includes(:sender).each do |notification|
  notification.sender
end
```

Is this because caching is enabled and there is no query made in first place? Is there any config that I should do to solve this?

Rails 5.1

Bullet 5.7.3

Comment: Can you please post the query

Comment: I just edit the post. Thanks.